# How can I get rid of the "file changed" warning in Visual Studio debugger

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019, visual-studio-debugging

When I'm debugging I will write notes where I hit issues, then continue with my debugging. I turn off Edit & Continue because with my notes, the code won't compile.

But what's annoying is I get a warning from the Visual Studio debugger every time I do this. And I know there's a way to turn this off, I just can't remember how (hard drive crash => reinstalled everything).

So, how can I turn it off?

> This source file has changed. It no longer matches the version of the
> file used to build the application being debugged.

[image]

And to clarify, I do want it to compile before starting the debugger. It's once I've started debugging I want it to silently accept and code editing I do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uncheck Options > Debugging > General > "Require source files to exactly match the original version".

Is that what you are looking for?